# Is there a dynamic way of displaying elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array $phrases where each cell either stores a phrase which is to be displayed to the user or else a "***" which signifies that an input element is to be placed at that position. I have attached an image to make myself clearer.

```
$phrases[0] = "Lorem ipsum dolor";
$phrases[1] = "***";
$phrases[2] = "consectetur adipiscing elit";
$phrases[3] = "***";
$phrases[4] = "***";
$phrases[5] = "quis nostrud exercitation";
```

[image]

My question is: how can I make my code adapt to any given array?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var $phrases = [], htmlString = "";
$phrases[0] = "Lorem ipsum dolor";
$phrases[1] = "***";
$phrases[2] = "consectetur adipiscing elit";
$phrases[3] = "***";
$phrases[4] = "***";
$phrases[5] = "quis nostrud exercitation";

for (var i = 0; i < $phrases.length; i++) { //loop through $phrases
  if ($phrases[i] == "***")
    htmlString += "<input type='text'>" //needs input
  else
    htmlString += "<span>" + $phrases[i] + "</span>"; //known value
}

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = htmlString; //place our htmlString on the page
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```